# App Store Receipt sometimes returns unexpected receipt

Tags: ios, swift, appstore-approval

I'm testing the restore process for an auto-renewing subscription. The testing has involved purchasing the subscription multiple times on the same device using different sandbox accounts.

I'm testing on three devices: iPhone, iPad and iPod. On the iPad I have the following problem:

If I keep polling the receipt from NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL, some minutes later, I suddenly get a different receipt associated with an earlier purchase under a different sandbox id. This is still a valid receipt, but is not associated with the sandbox user that is currently signed in. And I checked: the logged in user hasn't changed.

If I remove the app from the iPad and reinstall, refresh the receipt with SKReceiptRefreshRequest the first time he gets the right receipt, but some minutes later he takes back the receipt from the previous sandbox user.

Anyone an idea what causes this? Strange is that I did the same actions on iPod and iPhone, but on that devices everything is working fine.

Comment: are you sure that you are logging out from App Store during testing?

Comment: I'm logged in in AppStore with test Sandbox ID. Is it necessary to logout from AppStore while testing?

Answer (score 0):

Before Testing in sandbox mode, You must **logout from AppStore** if anyother accounts are logged in, Then only you can able to test an App in sandbox ID.If not app misbehaves and you cannot able to get the expected receipt from appstore.

Also confirm the app using sandbox url in testing,below is sandbox mode apple server url
https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/

**Steps to test In-App in SandBox**

1.Log Out from app stores if anyother accounts logged in.

2.Login with sandbox tester accounts.